# Value of longitude of central meridian for sinusoidal projection

Tags: coordinate-system, envi

I am trying to project a PDS 3 dataset into sinusoidal projection using ENVI. How do I calculate the longitude of central meridian value?

It is required for projecting the dataset. I have four corner reticules selenographic coordinates of the dataset.

Comment: `Lm = (L1 + L2) / 2`

Comment: Thank you @Vince . These coordinates form a boundary that is not aligned along the longitudes and they don't form a rectangle. Their footprint forms a irregular polygon with shorter width at the bottom. So do i take the left most and right most longitude for the L1 and L2 values?

Comment: This is the sort of information that belongs in the question (along with a screenshot). Please **edit** the question to contain these details.